# How to model an OLAP hypercube in Haskell

Tags: haskell

My thoughts so far were:

**Types**

a hypercube is a (discrete) function from one or more Dimensions to some value. I wanted to use Enumeration types for the Dimensions and ended up with this typeclass:

`class (Eq a, Ord a, Show a, Enum a, Bounded a) => Dimension a`

which allowed me to use this

```
data Age = Young | Adult | Old    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Enum, Bounded)
instance Dimension Age
```

and similar types as Dimensions.

A 2dimensional cube where the values have the type `Double` then has the type

```
cube2D :: (Dimension a, Dimension b) => a -> b -> Double
```

**Operations**

I can rotate the cube easily:

`cube2D' p a = cube2D a p`

I can get all possible values ("arguments") of a Dimension and for a 1D cube I can also get the possible results

```
arguments :: Dimension a => [a]
arguments = enumFrom minBound

results :: (Dimension a) => (a -> r) -> [r]
results cube = fmap cube arguments
```

This allows me to collapse a cube by one dimension, e.g. by replacing it by the sum of all results:

```
sum2D :: (Dimension a, Dimension b, Num r) => (a->b->r) -> a -> r
sum2D = fmap (sum . results)
```

**So far so good**

but `sum2D` only works for a cube with two Dimensions. I can write a similar function for a 3D cube and another one for a 4D cube. I suspect that most yet-to-be implemented operations will face the same problem. That means, my abstraction of *Hypercube* isn't really worth its salt.

I am not sure if I started on the wrong foot, or if my attempt to have an arbitrary number of Dimensions just doesn't go well with type-safety.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason you can’t do `cubeND :: (Dimension a) => [a] -> Double`, then `sumND :: (Dimension a, Num r) => ([a] -> r) -> [a] -> r`? If you want to make it more type-safe then it should be possible to use heterogeneous lists of dimensions rather than just normal lists: `cubeND :: DimHList ds -> Double`, `sumND :: Num r => (DimHList (d ': ds) -> r) -> DimHList ds -> r` (with a suitable definition of `DimHList`). If this looks like a useful approach I can expand this into a full answer.

Comment: I’ve thought about this a bit more and this preliminary definition of `DimHList` seems to work: `data DimHList ds where { DHNil :: DimHList '[]; DHCons :: Dimension d => d -> DimHList ds -> DimHList (d ': ds) }`. But I haven’t tested it too extensively yet — I’ll have to investigate this more fully later when I’ve got more time.

Comment: Well if it's really a hyper *cube*, all the dimensions will be the same.  I might use `cubeND :: (Dimension a) => (Fin n -> a) -> r`, where [`Fin`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Fin.Base.html#Fin) is the standard finite set construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno what the `Eq` and `Ord` constraints are, but I'd replace `Enum` and `Bounded` by [`Finite`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.1.1/docs/Data-Universe-Class.html#t:Finite). For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
data Age = Young | Adult | Old deriving (Enum, Bounded, Universe, Finite)
```

At first it doesn't like like we've won yet. The difference here is that the existence of these:

```
instance (Finite a, Finite b) => Finite (a, b)
instance Finite ()
```

So, now, instead of `a -> b -> Double`, use `(a,(b,())) -> Double`. Now you can rotate the first two dimensions of an n-dimensional thing:

```
rotate :: ((a,(b,c)) -> r) -> ((b,(a,c)) -> r)
rotate cube2D (p,(a,rest)) = cube2D (a,(p,rest))
```

You can sum along all dimensions:

```
sumNd :: (Finite a, Num r) => (a->r) -> r
sumNd f = sum [f a | a <- universeF]
```

Comment: Good. What's still haunting me is the following: isn't `a -> b -> Double`  isomorphic to `(a,(b,())) -> Double` ? I thought I should be able to do the same with plain functions, but somehow I can't. What is the underlying reason for this? What does `(,)` have over `(->)`?

Comment: They are isomorphic but not equal. Mucking with arbitrary-arity functions is *possible*, but requires significantly more complicated type-level machinery than mucking with known-arity functions. For a crisp idea of the difference: if you are using `(a,...) -> r` style, and you have something of shape `X -> Y`, you know that `X` is all the arguments and `Y` the result; but if you are using `a -> ... -> r` style, and you have something of shape `X -> Y`, then you don't know whether `X` is just the first argument (with `Y` again being some `W -> Z`) or whether `Y` is the result.

Comment: Right, that's where I got stuck: "what is the argument-type of an n-ary function?". I had put some home in CPS, but didn't come up with anything usable.  

However, even with the pair construction, I had trouble counsuming the arguments in any way, because I never knew whether I'm done or not. Obviously I cannot pattern-match on (). Any ideas on that?

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg One word: typeclasses.